# How to reload the parent page passing with ID value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is my parent page URL.

```
http://localhost:51907/BenefitBuilder/BvIndex/Index#
```

In this Page I have Add new record button. when i click this button pop up window will come I have some text boxes and dropdown list boxes.

my pop up window URL is this

```
http://localhost:51907/BenefitBuilder/bvIndex/CreateNewVariable/0
```

after I create I am closing the current Popup window.

I need to load the parent page with this URL

```
/BenefitBuilder/bvIndex/Index/" + bvId + "?bvIndex-mode=select
```

//bvId is newly created variable ID

Please can any body help me out how to load the parent window

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple, in the popup use:

```
opener.location.href =  "/BenefitBuilder/bvIndex/Index/" + bvId + "?bvIndex-mode=select";
```

This also closes the popup since the parent (opener) becomes invalid!